# Read words from a file one by one

Tags: c++, file, eof

I have a text file which looks like the following:

[szavak.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOhLq.jpg)

I want to read these words one by one to an array. I tried the following, but it nohow works.

```
string fajlnev = "szavak.txt";
ifstream fajl(fajlnev.c_str());

int i=0;
int db=0;
string line;

while (!fajl.eof())
{
    getline(fajl, line);
    db++;
}

string words[db];
for(i=0; i<db; i++)
{
    fajl>>words[i];
}

for(i=0; i<db; i++)
{
    cout<<words[i];
}
```

Could you please tell me where did I do bad?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't do `while (!fajl.eof())`, also you read the entire file line by line but then try to keep reading (that won't work: you are already at end of file!). Plus, `string words[db];` is not standard C++ when `db` is not a constant expression.

Comment: Could you provide a code please? Because I am really new to C++.

Comment: Any good book or tutorial for C++ should cover the basics of IO. `std::vector<std::string> v; std::string word; while (fajl >> word) v.push_back(word);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an [`istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) together with the [`vector` constructor taking an iterator pair](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/). Here is an example of a program placing its own source code in such a vector (and then printing it out):

```
#include <vector>                                                                                                                               
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>


using namespace std;


int main()
{
    ifstream in{"stuff.cpp"};
    vector<string> words{
        istream_iterator<string>{in},
        istream_iterator<string>{}};
    for(const auto &s: words)
        cout << s << endl;
}
```

(If you use this, make sure to build using c++11 settings.)